# Flow-Project tutorial 04 visualizer_rllib.py error

Tags: python, flow-project, rllib

I am new to flow and working through the examples. In tutorial 04 visualize example I get an attribute error. The code in the cell is

```
!python ../flow/visualize/visualizer_rllib.py data/trained_ring 200 --horizon 2000
```

and the error I get is:

```
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/experimental/tf_utils.py", line 186, in set_weights
    self.assignment_nodes[name] for name in new_weights.keys()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What is you ray version?

Try using ray 0.8.0. I think the latest stable version 1.0.1 might not be compatible.